# Create MS SQL Server function from dll assembly with ref parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, clr, sql-function

I want to create a function from an C# library that I've successfully registered in a MS SQL Server database as an assembly. The function's signature in C# looks like this:

```
public static double DensityD11162Relative(double observedDensity, 
                                           double observedTemperature, 
                                           double observedPressure, 
                                           ref int errorCode)
```

In order to use this function in SQL server I tried creating the function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION DensityD11162Relative(@observedDensity float, 
                                    @observedTemperature float,
                                    @observedPressure float,
                                    @errorCode int) 
    RETURNS float
    AS
    EXTERNAL NAME [Flowcal.ApiVcfLibrary].[Flowcal.ApiVcfLibrary.Customary.Original.Lubricants].DensityD11162Relative
```

However, this results in the following error message:

```
Msg 6580, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DensityD11162Relative, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
Declarations do not match for parameter 4. .NET Framework reference and T-SQL OUTPUT parameter declarations must match.
Msg 6552, Level 16, State 3, Procedure DensityD11162Relative, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
CREATE FUNCTION for "DensityD11162Relative" failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@errorCode" do not match.
```

The message states that the fourth parameter is of the wrong type, which makes sense because the C# signature shows that it needs a `ref int` argument.
**My question is: Can I pass a ref argument (or placeholder) when creating a SQL function from an assembly? If so, how? If not, is there any way around this without writing a wrapper in C#?**

I'm using SQL Server 2017

Comment: You should presumably declare that as `@errorCode int OUTPUT` to allow it to be treated similarly to by-ref.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not allowed:
Msg 181, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DensityD11162Relative, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
Cannot use the OUTPUT option in a DECLARE, CREATE AGGREGATE or CREATE FUNCTION statement.

Comment: Functions cannot have output parameters. So you know the answer - you cannot implement this directly as a function.

Comment: Too bad, I guess we're gonna have to write a wrapper. Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have control over both the DLL and the function, you could remove the ref parameter for ErrorCode and just return a string from your method that contains something like:

```
double|errorCode
```

Then in SQL you can split the string result and cast it to a float and an int on the client.

(I know there is a more efficient way of writing this, it is more clear breaking out each step)

```
Declare @StringResult nvarchar(50)
Declare @Result float
Declare @Delimiter nvarchar(1)
Declare @SeperateIndex int
Declare @ErrorCode int

Set @Delimiter = '|'

-- Example return value
Set @StringResult = '50|-1100'

Set @SeperateIndex = CharIndex(@Delimiter,@StringResult)

Set @Result = Convert(float,Substring(@StringResult,0,@SeperateIndex))
Set @ErrorCode = Convert(int, Substring(@StringResult, @SeperateIndex + 1, 
Len(@StringResult) - @SeperateIndex + 1))

Select @Result, @ErrorCode
```

In this example the results look like:

```
50  -1100
```

Just an idea.

Comment: We're writing a wrapper and we don't actually care about the error code, so it's gonna be even simpler than your solution. Nonetheless, thanks for the help!